# How to make summary report views

Tags: views

im trying to make a report in a view from other view(a table). i've tried view calculator and it's not what i want.

i want it like this :
Total people below 20 years old : xxx 
Total Male : xxx
Total Female : xxx
Total people that have *** : xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make 1 View per *report* you want. Using Views `aggregates` and filter conditions you should be able to generate the values you want.

Then make 1 master View and use `views attachments` to build your single massive report page by showing all these reports in that page view.